# Selection of database

Tags: database, performance, nosql, replication, couchbase

I want to develop a warehouse management application, where I need to achieve very less latency, higher performance, and replication also. As this application starts with small and grows over the period I need to consider minimum cost in the beginning. I'm thinking of couchbase but it requires more cost to setup cluster and nodes.

Can you help me to choose the appropriate database for this? Any kind of suggestion and guidance would be great. Thank You

Comment: This is sort of off-topic for SO. But if you want my advise, Postgres would be a great starting point for something like this.

Comment: @DroidX86, Thanks for the reply. Any idea on couchbase db?

Comment: Have you read HN today? Specifically this link: https://blog.bradfieldcs.com/you-are-not-google-84912cf44afb

Answer (score 2):

Couchbase employee here.

In terms of costs, there is no big difference compared to most relational databases. Although we do recommend to have at least 3 nodes in a production environment (so even if you lose 2 nodes, your database still is available) is perfectly fine to run one or two.

Additionally, as CB also provides Full-Text Search support, it can help you to save a few extra dollars as you won't need an ElastiSearch or Solr node running for some use cases.

In terms of performance at scale, I think that is where couchbase really shine, and cross data center replication is also a feature heavily used (many clients have clusters with +40 or +85 nodes replicating to other clusters around the world ). If you believe in benchmarks, here is one that worth to check : https://resources.couchbase.com/c/altoros-nosql-performance-benchmark?x=N-I_ik

I don't know a lot about your usecase, so I can't say for sure, but in general, Couchbase is a very good choice whenever you need scalability and speed, those are the primary reasons why people come to CB.

The only thing that you should pay attention is to how you model your data, Document Databases expects that you to have a denormalized data model, so you can't simply structure everything as you do in an RDBMS. Here is a short tutorial about it:
https://blog.couchbase.com/json-data-modeling-rdbms-users/

PS: Couchbase also has CouchbaseLite, which is a mobile database that automatically synchronizes with the remote database. It is pretty handy if you need to build apps that are offline first

Comment: thanks for answering. Will Couchbasse suits for my requirements?. As I have concerned with cost also, Couchbase requires more compute capacity. What if I start with PostgreSQL and later migrating to Couchbase over the period will it be a tedious task?.

Comment: low latency, higher performance, and replication: certainly yes. Migrating from postgress is also an option, but it will really depends on how you will model your data. My point is if you know that you will need a Document Database, and those requirements are really mandatories then start with it directly, otherwise sticky with relational.